# Pressure and temperature relation of Novec 1230

Tags: temperature, vapor-pressure, gas-phase-chemistry

I am working on a concept turbine for a school project which operates at low temperature so it's necessary for me to have a pressure temperature relation of this chemical or novec 7100 also is okay..  i looked it on the internet couldn't find the graph or any tables so if anyone is aware about this please help me out.. like what would the pressures be at 100 °C for 1 mole given a volume of 1m³

Comment: Since you are asking "what would the pressures be at 100 °C for 1 mole" (a question that doesn't make much sense), I guess you might want to read about the difference between intensive and extensive properties again.

Answer (score 4):

Novec™ 1230 is basically just 1,1,1,2,2,4,5,5,5-nonafluoro-4-(trifluoromethyl)pentan-3-one. The pressure–temperature relation is given by the manufacturer as a graph:

[image: Novec 1230]

Novec™ 7100 is a mixture of 1,1,1,2,3,3-hexafluoro-3-methoxy-2-(trifluoromethyl)propane and 1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4-nonafluoro-4-methoxybutane. The pressure–temperature relation is given by the manufacturer as an unfortunate value-equation:

$$\ln p=22.415-3641.9\left[1/(T+273)\right]$$

where
$p$ is pressure in pascal and
$T$ is temperature in degrees Celsius.